# Method invocation failed because System.Object[]] does not contain a method name indexOf in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have error IndexOf when i tried to run the following powershell script. Any advise

```
$unlicensedUsers = Get-MsolUser -UnlicensedUsersOnly
foreach ($aUser in $unlicensedUsers)
{
   if ($unlicensedUsers.IndexOf($aUser) % 10 -eq 0) {
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor yellow $unlicensedUsers.IndexOf($aUser)
   }
}
```

Error:

> IndexOf : Method invocation failed because System.Object[]] does not contain a method name indexOf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IndexOf()` is a method on the `List<T>` type, which is usually not used in PowerShell. Most of the time the variables that you use in `foreach` are going to be object arrays, as in your example, or some other type of collection. Object arrays don't have an equivalent method, so you'll have to hold your own copy of the array index:

```
$unlicensedUsers = Get-MsolUser -UnlicensedUsersOnly
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $unlicensedUsers.count; $i++)
{
    if ($i % 10 -eq 0) {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor yellow $i
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a static [`[Array]::IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.indexof.aspx) method, but in this case the `for` loop is definitely the better approach.

Comment: Indeed, the solution is the right one, but the explanation is incorrect: Cmdlet output is collected in `[object[]]` arrays by PowerShell, and such `System.Array` instances implement `.IndexOf()` by way of an _explicit_ interface implementation of `IList.IndexOf()`, which PSv2 doesn't surface, but PSv3+ does.

Answer (score 2):

[Nacht's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27162960/45375) contains the *correct solution*, but an *incorrect explanation*:

`System.Array` *instances* do have an `.IndexOf()` method via an *explicit* implementation of the [`IList.IndexOf()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ilist.indexof) interface method.

**Up to PSv2**, such *explicit* interface implementations were *not accessible at all*.

In **PSv3+**, explicit interface implementations are available *directly* on the implementing type, without the need to reference the interface, so your code would work, but Nacht's answer is still the better solution in the case at hand.

---

That said, even in PSv2 the `[System.Array]` *type* has a [*static* `.IndexOf()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof?view=netframework-2.0#System_Array_IndexOf_System_Array_System_Object_), which can be invoked as follows:

```
[array]::IndexOf($unlicensedUsers, $aUser) # return index of $aUser in array $unlicensedUsers
```